# The fastest way to loop through a list of 300k dictionaries?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, cython, performance-testing

I have a dict like this:

```
# I have a list of 300k dictionaries similar in format to the following
# I cannot assume the dictionaries are sorted by the "id" key
sentences = {"id": 1, "some_sentence" :"In general, the performance gains that indexes provide for read operations are worth the insertion penalty.",
             "another_sent": "She said, I had a dream you were playing for the Panthers.' I was like, that's weird because I'm in Indianapolis. But life has come full circle and her dream came true.”" }
# the double quotations are not a typo


# the re.findall is meant to split the the sentence into individual words excluding punctuations
temp = []
temp = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentences.get('some_sentence'))
temp += re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentences.get('another_sent'))
# temp = ["She", "said", "had",...]

# to delete case-sensitive duplicates so so if "My" and "my" is used in the sentence only "my" is kept
words = list(set(t.lower() for t in temp))

# I need to remove words of length less than 3
for i in words:
    if len(i) < 3:
       words.remove(i)

# put the list of words back into the dict

sentences["Words"] = words. # O(1)
```

I have a list of 300k dictionaries and right now it takes about 53 seconds to run on my mac
I don't really know what else I can do cut the time down from this

things I have tried:

- I have tried to use enumerate it made it a little slower
- I have tried to translate to C using the cython library but I did not get enough of an improvement because I could not translate the "re.findall" to C?

any ideas?

Comment: I would say 'Add more RAM' but as it's a mac.. buy a new mac? (seriously, use your local system status monitoring application to see if you're maxing out cpu or ram) you're doing something very intensive it might just be slow.

Comment: You might consider memoisation,  i.e. do this operation once and save the result somewhere into a cache, refresh the cache only when the source data changes.  It also might be the sort of thing that a relational database would be better at handling

Comment: How often do you need to remove 3 letters words from 300,000 dictionaries?

Comment: Can you explain *what* you are actually trying to do? "looping though 300k dicts" is not it.  You're doing that to achieve something. Explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's not clear why you are tokenizing with the regex `r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]"` only to throw all the punctuation away. Why not just start with `r"[\w']+"` ?

Comment: In addition to what the people above correctly pointed out: how does the data end up in a list of dictionaries to begin with? Do you start out with files, some online resource, etc.? Because you may have an XY problem here, where the best solution isn't the one you're asking about.

Comment: You are only showing a single dictionary, have you built a list of 300k sentences dicts that we don't see here? Do these all come from different files? You may get a speedup generating the list. You may get some speedup with a multiprocessing pool but the devil is in the details here.

Comment: @Tomalak you are right this is only one portion of a larger piece of code the dictionaries are documents to be isnerted into a mongodb database and I intend to use the words array to create an index for fast searching

Comment: @Mark Meyer not sure what you mean? I am throwing the punctuation away because I don't need it and it decreases the number of elements in my list that I need to loop through later

Comment: @Reblochon Masque on every iteration

Comment: Creating an index for fast searching is a solved problem. Extremely efficient software exists for this purpose (Apache Solr is one example). Don't roll your own indexer.

Comment: @Grismar I am reading in the dictionaries from a JSON file using the IJSON module in python but I have timed the read in which is only about 5 seconds

Comment: @water_bottle yes, I see you don't need the punctuation. My question is why are you capturing it in the regex in the first place? This part of your regex: `[.,!?;]` means you add all the punctuations to the final results only to throw them away.

Comment: @MarkMeyer oh really? I didn't know that's what the function was doing I thought `[.,!?;]` was capturing the punctuation to remove. what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1):

This might improve the exec time, and keep yourself out of trouble, as it is not a good idea to modify the list you are iterating over - it is hard to say if the improvement will be marginal or significant without profiling:

replace:

```
words = list(set(t.lower() for t in temp))
for i in words:
    if len(i) < 3:
       words.remove(i)   # this is an expensive operation on longer lists
```

with:

```
words = [word for word in set(t.lower() for t in temp) if len(word) > 3]
```

Comment: Seems like you could add that to `list(set(t.lower() for t in temp))` to only loop through once.

Answer (score 0):

You may get a speedup using multiple processes. Since you are on Mac, child processes get a view of the parent memory. By putting the sentence list is a global variable and only passing its index to child processes, you have a reasonably lean way to get data to the subprocesses. Still, the resulting words list needs to be passed back to the parent and that could negate the advantages of a pool. This method doesn't work on Windows which wouldn't see the global variable in the subprocess space.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import re

# I have a list of 300k dictionaries similar in format to the following
# I cannot assume the dictionaries are sorted by the "id" key
sentences = {"id": 1, "some_sentence" :"In general, the performance gains that indexes provide for read operations are worth the insertion penalty.",
                 "another_sent": "She said, I had a dream you were playing for the Panthers.' I was like, that's weird because I'm in Indianapolis. But life has come full circle and her dream came true.”" }
# the double quotations are not a typo

# imagine this is the 300k list of dicts
sentence_list = [sentences]

def worker(index):
    sentences = sentence_list[index]
    # the re.findall is meant to split the the sentence into individual words excluding punctuations
    temp = []
    temp = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentences.get('some_sentence'))
    temp += re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentences.get('another_sent'))
    # temp = ["She", "said", "had",...]

    # to delete case-sensitive duplicates so so if "My" and "my" is used in the sentence only "my" is kept
    words = list(set(t.lower() for t in temp))

    # I need to remove words of length less than 3
    for i in words:
        if len(i) < 3:
            words.remove(i)

    return index, words

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    for index, words in pool.imap_unordered(worker, range(len(sentence_list))):
        sentence_list[index]["word"] = words
```